# Parsing var in async callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm making a `.get` request to the ipinfo API to obtain the country code, then lowercase the string and parse it to a second function which should pickup the country code (example: us) and display the flag based on ISO 3166-1 alpha-2.

Although `countrySelect()` seems to be ignoring my country variable. 
A default country gets set on page load ('gb'), but then my callback should overwrite that.

Any idea of what's going on?

```
var country;
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/country", function(data) {
  var usercountry = data; // gets .country = ip location
  lusercountry = usercountry.toLowerCase(); // ie. GB to gb
  lusercountry = lusercountry.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // takes additional space off the string
  country = "'" + lusercountry + "'"; // adds '' to the .country string
  $("#country_selector").countrySelect("selectCountry", country);
});

$("#country_selector").countrySelect({
  defaultCountry: 'gb',
  //preferredCountries: []
});
```

Comment: Provided `data` is a country string (e.g., `"GB"`), that should be fine if that's how the `countrySelect` plugin works. When you use the debugger in your browser and set a breakpoint on the last line of that callback, what do you see for `country`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [documentation](https://github.com/mrmarkfrench/country-select-js), the method countrySelect takes a string when used with "selectCountry". There is no need to quote the string like this:

```
country = "'"+lusercountry+"'";
```

Simply pass `lusercountry` as is. i.e.

```
$("#country_selector").countrySelect("selectCountry", lusercountry);
```

Comment: The quotes *do* seem quite weird. I bet you're right about this.

Comment: lusercountry doens't seem to work, the var holds the string gb but does not pass it to the countrySelect(), strange.

Comment: @SimonCarucci There is no way you have to put quotes around it to pass a string. I tested your get request and the returned format, as you have it, is fine. It is strange if that doesn't work. Does the #country_select exist as an id? Can you post the HTML? Is country-select-js actually loaded?

Answer (score -1):

just pass **usercountry** to countrySelect, and you can minify your cod like that

```
 var usercountry = data.toLowerCase().trim();
 $("#country_selector").countrySelect("selectCountry", usercountry);
```

Use **trim()** instead of replace, there is only one additional space at the end, trim do the job